# Looking for a regex that can match any string that has 3 characters and 2 digits in any combination

Tags: regex

Currently I have:

```
/[a-z]{3}\d{2}
```

This matches `abc12` nicely but not `a7bb9`.

I have basic regex experience but I've never had to test for a fixed-length (5 characters) string that could have 60 million different combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?=(?:.*\d){2}).{5}$
```

- `^` beginning of the string
- `(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})` positive lookahead, there are at least 3 letters ahead with anything inbetween of them
- `(?=(?:.*\d){2})` positive lookahead, there are at least 2 digits ahead with anything inbetween of them
- `.{5}` the length of the string is 5
- `$` end of the string

It's using positive lookahead to make sure there are at least 3 letters and 2 digits in the string and the order doesn't matter while the length of the string is 5.

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/zXcEkx/1/)

Comment: You could prevent some backtracking by making the match a bit more specific instead of the `.*` `^(?=[a-z\d]{5}$)(?=(?:[a-z]*\d){2}[a-z]*$)(?:\d*[a-z]){3}\d*$`  See https://regex101.com/r/15AEPT/1

Comment: I was aware of that but I decided to make it simple and easy to understand than the performance wise. But it is a good addition, thanks!